# What do "they" refer to in this sentence?

Tags: pronouns

> Science is unique. Instead of making guesses, scientists follow a system designed to prove if their ideas are true or false. They constantly reexamine and test their theories and conclusions. Old ideas are replaced when scientists find new information that ***they*** cannot explain.

What do "they" in the last sentence refer to? Old ideas or scientists? Or could it mean both?

Answer (score -1):

It could mean both but I take meaning from the context. The reader is given a forceful sequence (almost a cadence) of notions: **scientists**; **their** ideas; **they** reexamine; **they** test; **they** replace; **they** find. Why break the sequence by suddenly assuming that ***they cannot explain*** refers to ideas?

Answer (score -1):

There is indeed a syntactical ambiguity within the sentence, but that ambiguity does not affect its overall point, as there is no real difference between saying

> the old ideas cannot explain it

and

> the scientists cannot explain it [by using these old ideas].